# Rails ActiveRecord - Select all objects by date, using only day, month, year, but ignoring the rest of the date's components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model named `Event`. I want to be able to get all Events that were created at some specific date which should be something like this

`Event.where(created_at: "20/01/2019".to_date)`

The issue is that the `created_at` field also contains minutes, second, etc, which I want to ignore. I only want to compare the date by day, month and year. Is there any way I can acchieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Date#beginning_of_day`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-beginning_of_day) and [`Date.end_of_day`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-end_of_day) both provided by `ActiveSupport` core extensions.

```
d = '2019-01-20'.to_date 
Event.where(created_at:(d.beginning_of_day..d.end_of_day))
```

This will not necessarily compare "...the date by day, month and year." but instead it will create a between clause that encompasses the entire day. If you want to use the `Hash` finder syntax this is probably the best way to go about it.

You could go with

```
Event.where(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('CAST',
     [Event.arel_table[:created_at].as('DATE')]
  ).eq(d)
)
```

If you really only want to compare the day, month and year.

Option 1 will result in

```
 events.created_at BETWEEN '2019-01-20 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-20 23:59:59'
```

Option 2 will result in

```
 CAST(events.created_at AS DATE) = '2019-01-20'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Event.where(created_at: d.to_time.all_day)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**